# Dataframe not showing in global environment R

Tags: r, environment-variables, bigdata, rstudio, ram

I have some RAM issues which cause some weird stuff to happen in Rstudio. I load in a large dataset (the BAG) containing all addresses in the Netherlands. Then I do some left joins with other public datasets like energy labels and monument status etc. This gives me a dataframe I called combined which has 9.5 million rows and about 80 columns. This used to take a while but otherwise work perfectly. Then I ran into some kind of unrelated error and had to reinstall R. After that, I now get a new error when loading these datasets -->
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 70.9 Mb
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 128.0 Mb

After the error interrupts my script I don't see the combined dataframe in my global environment but I can retrieve data from it from the console (see attached screenshot) using combined[1,1] for example. However if I try View(combined), I get a similar error after it's been loading for a while: cannot allocate vector of size 35 Mb error. R is taking up about 96% of my RAM memory (around 11-12 GB) so I'm assuming it's a full RAM error, but I don't get why I get it now since it used to work perfectly before.

While I've found a bunch of stuff online about sparse matrices and R SQL combo's etc., I find this weird because it didn't happen before. More RAM is on it's way which will hopefully solve this issue but I would like to understand why R is throwing me this error now, and why I can see some smaller dataframes in my global environment but I cannot see the 'combined' one, even though I can access it through the console.

I have reinstalled R, Rtools and Rstudio twice, problem persists. I am running the following version of R:

> R.version
>                  _
>   platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             mingw32
>   system         x86_64, mingw32
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          6.1
>   year           2019
>   month          07
>   day            05
>   svn rev        76782
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
>   nickname       Action of the Toes

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad laptop with an i7 8th gen processor and 16 GB of RAM. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a RStudio issue. The reason it works from the console but not in the viewer is presumably the viewer's RAM overhead, but not showing in the environment list may be a RStudio bug - consider reporting.

Comment: You could also try restarting your computer if you haven't done so recently. Also, you could try running your script in regular R. you may want to clean up your ```.Rdata``` as well

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. I've just tested it in RGui and it runs into the same error while running my script and while running View(combined).

Comment: @Cole apologies, we reacted at the same time. I've restarted my computer after every uninstall and install cycle.
What do you mean with clean up my .Rdata though? The bagadres-full.bin I load/save does not affect this error. If I download and extract a new dataset and run the rest of the script with that dataframe it gives me the same error.

Comment: As long as you can reproduce what's on your environment, see this: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-clear-the-r-environment/14303/7?u=col